# Сортировка ArrayList в Java

Tags: java, сортировка, arraylist

Мой код ищет по объему нужные файлы в директории, выводит их в формате "объем + путь к файлу", не могу настроить, чтобы вывод в консоль был отсортированным по объему файла (от большего к меньшему), причем нужно еще учесть, что у разных файлах объем выводиться в разных единицах (байты, мегабайты и т.п.) Менял ArrayList на TreeSet, а так же пробовал добавить Collections.sort(testList);
Collections.reverse(testList);
Но не помогло

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class  Main{

    public static final double MIN_LENGTH = 700;  //размер файла в байтах

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        getFiles(new File("C:/Users/Desktop"), fileList);
        
        for(File file: fileList) {
            if(file.length()>= 1073741824) {
                System.out.printf("%s Gb  %s%n",  file.length() / 1073741824, file); // в гигабайтах
            } else if(file.length()>= 1048576) {
                System.out.printf("%s Mb  %s%n",  file.length() / 1048576, file); // в мегабайтах
            } else if (file.length()>= 1024){
                System.out.printf("%s Kb  %s%n",  file.length() / 1024, file);  // выводит в килобайтах объем
            } else if (file.length()< 1024){
                System.out.printf("%s B  %s%n",  file.length(), file); // в байтах
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s Gb  %s%n",  file.length() / (1073741824 * 1024), file); // в терабайтах
            }
        }
    }

    private static void getFiles(File rootFile, List<File> fileList) {
        if (rootFile.isDirectory()) {
            File[] directoryFiles = rootFile.listFiles();
            if (directoryFiles != null) {
                for (File file: directoryFiles) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        getFiles(file, fileList);
                    } else {
                        if (file.isFile() && file.length() >= MIN_LENGTH) {
                            fileList.add(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с Java 8, можно сортировать список при помощи метода `List::sort`, в который нужно передать компаратор по размеру файла:

```java
fileList.sort(Comparator.<File>comparingLong(File::length).reversed());
```

Аналогично можно передать компаратор в метод `Collections.sort`:

```java
Collections.sort(fileList, Comparator.comparing(File::length, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

Comment: Да, спасибо все заработало как надо

Comment: Добрый день, ваш метод решил задачу сортировки, но в процессе доработки кода я добавил многопоточность в него, при которой один поток перебирал папки а другой перебирал файлы и выводил сразу в консоль список файлов соответствующих поиску, и принцип сортировки уже не работает этот, вы бы ни могли мне дать совет как настроить сортировку в новом коде? Ниже я могу его приложить) 3 дня безуспешно этим занимаюсь

Comment: Лучше задать это в новом вопросе, и обязательно добавить код

Comment: Хорошо, так и сделаю